# Specific where clause in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

So i have a mysql table with over 9 million records. They are call records. Each record represents 1 individual call. The columns are as follows:

```
CUSTOMER
RAW_SECS
TERM_TRUNK
CALL_DATE
```

There are others but these are the ones I will be using.
So I need to count the total number of calls for a certain week in a certain Term Trunk. I then need to sum up the number of seconds for those calls. Then I need to count the total number of calls that were below 7 seconds. I always do this in 2 queries and combine them but I was wondering if there were ways to do it in one? I'm new to mysql so i'm sure my syntax is horrific but here is what I do...

Query 1:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, SUM(RAW_SECS), COUNT(*)
FROM Mytable
WHERE TERM_TRUNK IN ('Mytrunk1', 'Mytrunk2')
GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(*)
FROM Mytable2
WHERE TERM_TRUNK IN ('Mytrunk1', 'Mytrunk2') AND RAW_SECS < 7
GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```

Is there any way to combine these two queries into one? Or maybe just a better way of doing it? I appreciate all the help!

Comment: no. not really. `sum(raw_secs)` and `raw_secs < 7` have contradictory purposes. You could fiddle with moving to `having raw_secs < 7`, but I'm guessing this won't produce what you want.

Comment: If you want to combine the queries, the output needs to be shaped the same.  If you had similar columns you could use a `UNION ALL` and get the results in one call.

Comment: I suppose second query's RAW_SECS is coming from the sum of the first query. Use `HAVING` for aggregated filter like `HAVING SUM(RAW_SECS) < 7` after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Just show the sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of achieving the expected outcome in a single query:

- conditional counting: use a case expression or if() function within the `count()` (or `sum()`) to count only specific records
- use self join: left join the table on itself using the id field of the table and in the join condition filter the alias on the right hand side of the join on calls shorter than 7 seconds

The advantage of the 2nd approach is that you may be able to use indexes to speed it up, while the conditional counting cannot use indexes.

```
SELECT m1.CUSTOMER, SUM(m1.RAW_SECS), COUNT(m1.customer), count(m2.customer)
FROM Mytable m1
LEFT JOIN Mytable m2 ON m1.id=m2.id and m2.raw_secs<7
WHERE TERM_TRUNK IN ('Mytrunk1', 'Mytrunk2')
GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```